# Product Rule For Limits

Tags: limits, continuity

I've been reading the product rule for limits and wondering if this proof is enough and if not, why.

Claim:
$f$ and $g$ are functions defined on an open interval $I$ with $c∈I$,  with $x∈I$

$lim_{x\to c}f(x) = F, lim_{x\to c}g(x) = G,$

then

$(lim_{x\to c}f(x)lim_{x\to c}G(x))=lim_{x\to c}(f(x)g(x))$

My attempt at a proof:

$\forall \sqrt\epsilon>0\exists \delta_1>0$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-F| < \sqrt \epsilon$

and

$\forall \sqrt\epsilon>0\exists \delta_2>0$ such that if $|x-c|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)-G| < \sqrt \epsilon$

let $\delta = min${$\delta_1,\delta_2$}

then $\forall |x-c| < \delta \implies=|(f(x)-F)(g(x)-G)|=|f(x)-F||g(x)-G| < \epsilon$
$\blacksquare$

Does this proof prove the claim? Many thanks.

Edit: misworded my question apologies!

Comment: If $c$ is fixed then you are asking it $FG=G^{2}$ which may not be true. I really don't understand this question at all.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, so f and g are functions defined on an open interval I with $c \in I$

Comment: Where have you defined $G(x)$?

Comment: Again with $x \in I$

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy's comments are trying to get you to notice that you have stated the question incorrectly. Are you actually trying to prove $\lim_{ x \to c} (f(x) g(x)) = FG$?

Comment: Yes, I am, I've used F and G to express in this case the limits exist.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! Took me forever to realise I'd stated the question incorrectly.

Comment: Your proof is not correct (although the result is, of course).  You need to prove that there's some interval in which $|f(x)g(x)-FG| \lt \epsilon$.  Your proof doesn't do that.

Comment: Fantastic, will work on this.

Comment: Hint consider $|(f(x)g(x) - Fg(x)) + (Fg(x) - FG)|$ use triangle inequality

Comment: I personally tend to go a step further before applying triangle inequality: $$|f(x)g(x) - FG| = |(f(x) - F)(g(x) - G) + F(g(x) - G) + G(f(x) - F)|.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll get you started with a technique that will help you select the $\delta$ you need.

$$|f(x)g(x)-FG| = |f(x)g(x)-f(x)G+f(x)G-FG|=|f(x)(g(x)-G)+G(f(x)-F)|
\leq |f(x)||g(x)-G|+|G||f(x)-F|.$$

I'll leave it to you to choose $\delta$ that makes each component of the sum small enough.